# How to create a boolean ValueAxis in am4chart?

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4, amcharts5

[my chart with values that are only two values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECdvP.png)

> 

so i want to have yaxis (valueAxis) to be 0 and 1, without 0.1,0.2,0.3,..., also if i could change 0 to 'offline' and 1 to'online'? tried everything but i cant seem to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you can:

- Set `valueAxis.min` and `valueAxis.max`
- Put a quite big value in `valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance`
- Define an adapter on `valueAxis.renderer.labels.template`

```js
am4core.ready(() => {

  let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

  chart.data = [
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-26").getTime(),
      value: 0
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-27").getTime(),
      value: 1
    },
    {
      date: new Date("2022-12-28").getTime(),
      value: 0
    }
  ];

  let dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());

  let valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
  valueAxis.min = 0;
  valueAxis.max = 1;
  valueAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 1000;
  
  valueAxis.renderer.labels.template.adapter.add("text", (label, target) => {
    if (target.dataItem && (target.dataItem.values.value.value === 0)) {
      return "Offline";
    } else if (target.dataItem && (target.dataItem.values.value.value === 1)) {
      return "Online";
    } else {
      return label;
    }
  });

  let series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.StepLineSeries());
  series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
  series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
  series.strokeWidth = 2;
  series.fillOpacity = 0.2;

});
```

```css
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>

<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```